# how can I do calculation of numbers from text file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have a text file named `t1.txt`, it contains:

```
300
400
500
600
```

Now I want to find how many numbers in this text are less than 450
And I give the following code:

```
b=0
for i in $(cat t1.txt)
do
  if [$i -lt 450]
  then
    ((b=b+1))
  fi
done
echo b
```

but it doesn't work.

What should I do?
Thank you.

Comment: `echo b` is very different than `echo $b`

Answer (score 1):

```
b=0
for i in $(cat t1.txt)
do
  # convert float to int
  i=$(echo $i | cut -d. -f1)
  if [ $i -lt 450 ] # comment: need spaces next to the the square brackets
  then
    ((b=b+1))
  fi
done
echo $b  # comment: need to $
```

Comment: what if the numbers in text file are not integer? They are float for example. It will show the error of `integer expression expected`

Comment: Bash cannot do floats on it's own, unless you something like `bc`. So if you have floats, there is no way to do an `if` on it. A hack is to drop the float part and make the number an integer.

Comment: I've just edited the answer to handle floats.

Answer (score 1):

Awk is good at this:

```
$ awk '$1<450{c++} END{print c+0}' t1.txt
2
```

How it works:

- `$1<450 {c++}`

  For any line for which the first field is less than 450, the variable `c` is incremented by one.
- `END{print c+0}`

  After we have read in all the lines, the value of `c` is printed.

The numbers can be integer or floating point.  Awk understands both.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read line
    do
            if [ "${line}" -lt "450" ]
            then
                    count=$((count+1))
            fi
    done < t.txt

    echo ${count}
```

Comment: This is indeed a good solution, but the answer could benefit from some explanation about how it works (and in particular where it differs from the one that didn't work for the OP)